# Запись png картинки без использования java.awt.image.BufferedImage

Tags: java, javafx, png

Вопрос: как превратить данные о **ширине/высоте** картинки в пикселях и её представление в виде 2D-**массива пикселей** (**координаты** + **цвет**) в **png**-файл *без использования java.awt.image.BufferedImage и javax.imageio.ImageIO*.

Не хочу работать с устаревшим awt пакетом. Ищу новые решения (Возможно, велосипед).

По сути, меня интересует, в каком **формате** нужно записывать файл картинки, т.е. в каком порядке в бинарный файл записывать данные о ширине/высоте картинки и её данные о пикселях.

Хочу записать данные из javafx.scene.image.Image (**WritableImage**) в **png** файл. Предварительно я вычитываю **pixelReader**'ом данные о пикселях изображения.

Спасибо.

Comment: Не очень понятно, в чем ваш вопрос - вас интересует просто формат файла? Так при чем тут тогда  `javafx.scene.image.Image` и всякое прочее? Читайте описание формата png и пишите байты в поток в соответствии с этим описанием. Или вы не знаете, где найти описание формата? Или вы хотите, чтобы вам его здесь в ответе описали?

Comment: Спасибо. Описание формата у меня есть. Прежде чем делать свою реализацию, я решил сначала узнать, не сделал ли кто-то то же самое раньше меня (что очень вероятно).